# How should I proceed in computing the radius of convergence when the term $a_k$ won't yield a nice formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to compute the radius of convergence for the power series of $g(z)=z^3 e^{z^3}$ and $h(z)=\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}$ around $0$. I am a bit confused on how to do it: I know the power series is: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ where $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$ but for these functions, this doesn't yield any recognizable closed form. The $n$-th derivatives for $g$ are:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & e^{z^2} z^2 \left(2 z^2+3\right) \\
 2 & 2 e^{z^2} z \left(2 z^4+7 z^2+3\right) \\
 3 & 2 e^{z^2} \left(4 z^6+24 z^4+27 z^2+3\right) \\
 4 & 4 e^{z^2} z \left(4 z^6+36 z^4+75 z^2+30\right) \\
 5 & 4 e^{z^2} \left(8 z^8+100 z^6+330 z^4+285 z^2+30\right) 
\end{array}$$

And the The $n$-th derivatives for $h$ are:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -\frac{z^2 \left(z^2-3\right)}{\left(z^2-1\right)^2} \\
 2 & -\frac{2 z \left(z^2+3\right)}{\left(z^2-1\right)^3} \\
 3 & 3 \left(\frac{1}{(z+1)^4}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^4}\right) \\
 4 & 3 \left(-\frac{4}{(z+1)^5}-\frac{4}{(z-1)^5}\right) \\
 5 & 60 \left(\frac{1}{(z+1)^6}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^6}\right) 
\end{array}$$

I don't see any recognizable formula for the values of these derivatives computed at $z_0=0.$ Although, I've computed each of these derivatives at $z=0$ and found that there are the following two sequences of values:

$$\left\{0,0,1,0,1,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{6},0,\dots\right\}$$

$$\{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots\}$$

In the first case, the values alternate and there is a subsequence converging to $0$. In the second case, it seems it continues alternating forever. How should I proceed in these cases?

Comment: $g(z)=z^3e^{z^3}$ is an entire function, so the radius of convergence is infinite.  You don't need to know the formula for the power series coefficients; look for the singularities of the function.

Comment: The power series for $h(z)$ converges iff the power series for $1/(1-z^2)$ converges. This is obvious if $z=0$. If $z\ne 0$ the terms of the series for $h(x)$ are just constant multiples (by the non-$0$ factor $z^3$) of the terms of  the power series for $1/(1-z^2).$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a standard theorem:

> Let $U\subset\Bbb{C}$ be an open set, $f:U\to \Bbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Let $a\in U$ and suppose $r>0$ is such that the open disc $D_r(a)$ lies in $U$. Then, $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(z-a)^n$ for all $z\in D_r(a)$.

This is pretty much what one proves in order to deduce that "holomorphic implies analytic". So, for any disc which lies inside the domain $U$ of holomorphy, the function has a power series expansion valid on that whole disc, and the crucial thing is that the coefficients of the power series do not depend on the radius $r$ of the disc (in the course of the proof of the theorem, one establishes that $\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta-a|=\rho}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-a)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta$ where $0<\rho<r$).

As a corollary, if $f$ is entire, then the theorem tells us that for any $r>0$, the series converges and equals $f$, in other words the radius of convergence is $\infty$. This is the case with $g(z)=z^3e^{z^3}$.

Next, for $h(z)=\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}$, it is clearly holomorphic on the unit disc $D_1(0)$, so the radius of convergence of the series is $\geq 1$. On the other hand, $h$ does not have a holomorphic extension past $z=\pm 1$, so the radius of convergence cannot be strictly larger than $1$, i.e the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something else that may also be useful for you: Remember that if $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^n$ then by Cauchy-Hadamard theorem the radius of convergence $R$ satisfies $1/R = \limsup (|a_n|)^{1/n}$. You can use this formula to justify that $e^z=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!}z^n$ has infinite radius of convergence, in particular this series converges if we evaluate it on $z^3$ so $e^{z^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}z^{3n}$ does also converge in the whole complex plane (we are simply evaluating the series at the number $z^3$, and the series converges at any complex number). Finally note that $g(z)=z^3e^{z^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}z^{3(n+1)}$ has infinite radius of convergence and this series must be the Taylor series of $g$ by unicity, we didn't have to calculate any derivative for $g$.

Now note that $\frac{1}{1-z^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1} z^{2n}$, using the geometric series formula, which is valid iff $|z|^2<1 \Leftrightarrow |z|<1$, however you can apply also the Hadamard formula to find that $R=1$. Since the series of $h(z)$ converges for $z\neq 0$ iff the series of $h(z)/z^3=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ converges (we are multiplying a series by a number), then the series of $h$ also have radius of convergence equal to $1$.